# attr/colorError not found error when using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4. I imported the recycler view library. Then it comes out the attr/colorError not found message.
This is app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.robyn.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
}
```

Whenever I add the two libraries implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2' and 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2', it comes out this error message:
[image]

I tried clean and rebuild, the error message is still there. I checked res/values/colors, the color values are there. Why I get this color error? If I want to use recycler view, what version of library should I import?

Comment: You should ideally match the compileSdkVersion

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Change the following details it will work fine,

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0-beta2"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. We develop an app that we update every 3 months or so, and it's so frustrating that - every time we open Android Studio - there are tons of updates, patches & "quickfixes" to download & apply before doing any development work. Can't say XCode is any better though, with all incompatible Swift versions. Yikes, sorry for the sudden outburst :) Thanks though for sharing the solution to this issue!

Comment: how can I upvote Fredrik's comment a million or so times

Comment: @Muthukrishnan Rajendran it's working friend. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

Also upgrading `compileSDKVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to 26 (it was 25) fixed the issue for me:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

}
```

In general, make sure to keep all the versions consistent (compile, build, appcompat libraries).

This is to ensure compilation and stability on runtime (one can also see lint warning about the latter if lint finds differnet support library versions)

Answer (score 4):

***Revision 26.0.0 Beta 2***

> Please note that 26.0.0-beta2 is a pre-release version. Its API
>   surface is subject to change, and it does not necessarily include
>   features or bug fixes from the latest stable versions of Support
>   Library.

For your problem you can use  **"26.0.0-beta2"** . It will be better if you use **[Stable](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)** Version .

Comment: i have same issue with stable version (26.0.1)

Comment: @deviant Google dev. should look on that matter. Day by day new bug coming

Comment: @deviant same problem for `26.0.0-beta2` ?

Answer (score 3):

pasting following code at Android/build.gradle bottom helped me:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same error when my app is on appcompat-26 and tries to include an Android library which in turn uses appcompat-25.
My solution has so far been to keep the app on 25 as well.

I have no idea if it's supposed to be like this. Surely you must be able to publish a library that uses the support lib version X and have it run in apps using support lib version X+1.

I am using AS 3.0-beta7 so maybe it's resolved on stable 3.0 which was released a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `minSdk`:

e.g.:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.0-beta2"
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.parse.starter"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found this "attr/colorError" error occurred when I had created product flavours and had put the "legacy" after the "current" in my build.gradle (in "app" folder). When I put the "legacy" before the "current" (as shown below) then the error went away. Maybe the lower "versionCode" or "Sdk" versions need to appear first?

```
   flavorDimensions "legacycurrent"
   productFlavors {

      legacy {
               dimension "legacycurrent"
               versionCode 98
               minSdkVersion 9
               targetSdkVersion 25
               compileSdkVersion 25
             }
      current {
               dimension "legacycurrent"
               versionCode 99
               minSdkVersion 14
               targetSdkVersion 26
               compileSdkVersion 26
             }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

FWW - For future searchers, I've added the code below to my root build.gradle to search down through dependencies and fix them to match my root project.  There are probably caveats and reasons why this is a bad idea, but it consistently works for me.

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {subproject ->
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code in `android/build.gradle` fixed my error.

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 31
                buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```